# How to check contacts present on the app?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contacts

There are many apps on the play store which show the contacts (after taking permission from the user) and a company logo at the end of each user, which denotes whether a user is on the app or not.
This flow helps to invite the set of users.
When I implementing all of the above, things got really complicated, suppose the bottom nav has a dedicated action say **Contacts**, when I fetch the contacts from the known method(Content Resolver query), First It's too slow, so I put the contacts to the sqlite db, but it's still slow. **How to extract contacts efficiently ?**.Like **OYO ROOMS APP** has a dedicated Bottom Nav Action *Invite & earn* which does exactly the thing I want. If anybody know how to do it effectively, please do let me know.

```
private void fetchContactsFromSystem() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            final int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            final int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            String name, number;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);
                number = number.replaceAll(" ", "");
                if (!phoneNumberSet.contains(number.trim())) {
                    sqliteDatabaseHelper.insertData(name.trim(), number.trim());
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    contact.setName(name);
                    contact.setPhone(number);
                    contact.setInvited(false);
                    contactList.add(contact);
                    phoneNumberSet.add(number);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Projection String array**

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
};
```

**Getting the data from the sqlite**

```
    private void setUpFromSqliteDatabase(Cursor cr) {
    String name, number;
    boolean isInvite;
    while (cr.moveToNext()) {
        name = cr.getString(0);
        number = cr.getString(1);
        isInvite = cr.getInt(2) == 1;
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setName(name);
        contact.setPhone(number);
        contact.setInvited(isInvite);
        contactList.add(contact);
    }
    cr.close();
}
```

**SQLite Helper Class**

```
public class SqliteDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
public static final String NAME = "NAME";
public static final String PHONE_NUMBER = "PHONE_NUMBER";
public static final String IS_INVITED = "IS_INVITED";

public SqliteDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (NAME TEXT, PHONE_NUMBER TEXT PRIMARY KEY, IS_INVITED INTEGER DEFAULT 0)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String name,String phone) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(PHONE_NUMBER,phone);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    db.close();
    return result != -1;
}

public void updateInvitedData(String phoneNumber) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(IS_INVITED, 1);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "PHONE_NUMBER = ?",new String[] {phoneNumber});
    db.close();
}

public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
}
```

}

Comment: "First It's too slow" - Not in my experience. I measured it myself once, and querying 10k contacts using a `ContentResolver` took 200ms tops.

Comment: Well, I don't know how you did that, If you'll post something then It would be really helpful, I did using Content Resolver and query return the cursor and I use the cursor to extract the name and phone number of user. All of this thing in another thread. But its slow, that's why I asked. Someone said extract contact in batches. I don't how to extract contact in batches if you know , please help me.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you are using to conduct the query and construct your "Contact" POJOs (or however else you use them in Java code). Have you done any kind of profiling as well to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: @PPartisan I have updated the question and posted the used code, the function fetchContactFromSystem() runs in Async Thread.

Comment: That looks quite straightforward. I expect the most expensive work there will be `replaceAll()` and `contains()` (you don't need to call `contains` for a `Set` either by the way, you can just do `if(set.add(...)) {/*This item is being added for the first time, so update your db here*/})` - how many contacts are you querying, and how long do you find this process takes? Also, the `insert` is probably slowing you down quite a lot - it would be more efficient to batch those and do one bulk insert at the end.

Comment: Well, It runs only for the first time to extract contact from the system and store it at local sqlite, and after that query the sqlite to get the contact

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of small areas you could increase efficiency, buy the main one would come from batching your inserts. Here's an example of how you could modify your existing code to achieve this.

```
private void fetchContactsFromSystem() {
    final ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
    final String sort = String.format("%s ASC", Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    try(Cursor cursor = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, sort)) {
        if(cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) return;

        final List<Contact> insert = new LinkedList<>();
        final int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        final int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);

        do {
            final String name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
            final String number = cursor.getString(numberIndex).replaceAll("\\s+","");

            //"true" if number doesn't already exist in the Set
            if(phoneNumberSet.add(number)) {
                //Can make this immutable and pass info in constructor
                final Contact contact = new Contact(name, number, false);
                contactList.add(contact);
                insert.add(contact);  
            }       
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        //Conduct bulk insert of "insert" list here
        bulkInsert(insert);
    }

}

private void bulkInsert(List<Contact> contacts) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = sqliteDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(2);
            cv.put(NAME_ID, contact.name());
            cv.put(NUMBER_ID, contact.number());
            db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's works for sure for the first time user on the screen, and inserting all the contact to sqlite. That's the mistake I made I admitted. But after that User coming to screen and I query to the sqlite but that process is also very slow for contacts of about 720

Comment: Can you add how you query those contacts to your question?

Comment: I've added the sqlite helper class.

Comment: It looks OK to me - there are things I would change but nothing that would majorly impact performance. I'd suggest you try and do some profiling because I expect your performance issue is taking place somewhere else - 720 contacts in nothing, and the query should be near instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

if the expected result is a set of phones, you don't need to sort by `DISPLAY_NAME`, sort is usually an expensive feature in SQLite.

Also, I wouldn't store the results in a local SQLite, it will cause you issues when trying keep the local copy, and the updated Contacts DB in sync (e.g. when the user adds or removes a contact).

Comment: Any efficient way to do it ?. It  literally takes 20 seconds to query the local SQLite to display of just 720 contacts.